# Java - How to verify for non-allowed characters?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to throw an Exception if a String value contains any different character that doesn't be a digit `[0-9]`, or a hyphen `(-)`, or semicolon `(;)` or an exclamation `(!)`.

For example, this is a completely correct string: 1;3;5-9;!12-14

But this one is not: 1;3abc;5~9;?12*41

I'm trying to use the code below but it's always failing:

```
String values = "1;3;5-9;!12-14"
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\d*]|[\\;]|[\\-]|[\\!]");
if (!pattern.matcher(values).matches()) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: A handy tool (even if not directly for Java regex syntax): https://regex101.com/r/6ZojHU/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex `[\\d*]|[\\;]|[\\-]|[\\!]` uses 4 times a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will match a character which is inside a single character class.

You could put them all in one character class, assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string and repeat that one or more times:

[`^[0-9;!-]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/BaIhur/1)